# ¿Cómo filtrar filas de un DataFrame de Pandas con una lista de datos contenidos parcialmente en una columna?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo una DataFrame de Pandas compuesta con los datos de varios ficheros csv:

```
esfuerzos

                    Bar/Point/Case                  FX (kN) FY (kN) FZ (kN)
forces_1.csv    0   300/ origin (189)/ 1000 (C)     65.29   -7.13   982.38
                1   300/ end (190)/ 1000 (C)        61.40   -7.13   971.66
                2   301/ origin (332)/ 1000 (C)     962.68  7.11    251.21  
                3   301/ auto x=2,000 (-)/ 1000 (C) 935.30  7.11    251.21
                4   301/ auto x=2,000 (+)/ 1000 (C) 736.89  -11.31  -725.70
                5   301/ end (198)/ 1000 (C)        709.51  -11.31  -725.70
forces_2.csv    0   300/ origin (189)/ 1000 (C)     95,70   -14,72  1190,90
                1   300/ end (190)/ 1000 (C)        91,81   -14,72  1180,17 
                2   301/ origin (332)/ 1000 (C)     1169,15 14,68   304,34
                3   301/ auto x=2,000 (-)/ 1000 (C) 1141,77 14,68   304,34  
                4   301/ auto x=2,000 (+)/ 1000 (C) 943,88  -31,26  -673,71 
                5   301/ end (198)/ 1000 (C)        916,50  -31,26  -673,71
```

Si dentro de la columna `‘Bar/Point/Case’` quiero filtrar los resultados por un número de barra uso `contains`:

```
barra = '300'
esfuerzos_barra = esfuerzos[esfuerzos['Bar/Point/Case'].str.contains(barra)]
esfuerzos_barra

                    Bar/Point/Case              FX (kN) FY (kN) FZ (kN)
forces_1.csv    0   300/ origin (189)/ 1000 (C) 65.29   -7.13   982.38
                1   300/ end (190)/ 1000 (C)    61.40   -7.13   971.66
forces_2.csv    0   300/ origin (189)/ 1000 (C) 95.70   -14.72  1190.90
                1   300/ end (190)/ 1000 (C)    91.81   -14.72  1180.17
```

Si quiero filtrar por una lista de datos contenidos en `‘Bar/Point/Case’` uso `isin`:

```
bpc = [' 300/ origin (189)/ 1000 (C)', ' 301/ origin (332)/ 1000 (C)']
esfuerzos_bpc = esfuerzos[esfuerzos['Bar/Point/Case'].isin(bpc)]
esfuerzos_bpc

                    Bar/Point/Case              FX (kN) FY (kN) FZ (kN)
forces_1.csv    0   300/ origin (189)/ 1000 (C) 65.29   -7.13   982.38
                2   301/ origin (332)/ 1000 (C) 962.68  7.11    251.21  
forces_2.csv    0   300/ origin (189)/ 1000 (C) 95.70   -14.72  1190.90 
                2   301/ origin (332)/ 1000 (C) 1169.15 14.68   304.34
```

Pero, ¿cómo hago para filtrar por una lista de datos contenidos parcialmente en `‘Bar/Point/Case’`? Por ejemplo

```
barras = [300, 301]
```

(Se entiende que la DataFrame `esfuerzos` contiene bastantes más barras.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `str.contains` también. Dado que trata la subcadena como una expresión regular basta con usar un `or` (`|`) entre las opciones:

```
barras = '300|301'
esfuerzos_barra = esfuerzos[esfuerzos['Bar/Point/Case'].str.contains(barras)]
```

Existe un problema con esto, si existen filas que contienen un '300' o '301' en otro lugar de la cadena que no sea el perteneciente a `barra` obtendriamos resultados erróneos, por ejemplo:

> 340/ end (300)/ 1000 (C),916.50,31.26,-673.71

seria capturada como válida cuando el valor de barra no es '300' ni '301', pero existe un '300' en la cadena.

La solución es acotar la expresión más aún, por ejemplo (por tus ejemplo parece que esta columna empieza con un espacio):

```
barras = ' 300/| 301/'
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Gracias.